# Grappling hook script sometimes causing jitter

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I am trying to implement a grappling hook mechanic.

My grappling script is attached to my camera that is attached to the player.

Sometimes when I try to grapple onto a wall, it causes jitterting when the `grapSpeed` variable is 40 or more. When it's more than 40, it happens almost all the time and it's more intense.

My walls' rigidbodies are set to no gravity, kinematic, freeze position and rotation. My player isn't kinematic and has collision set to continuous dynamic.
Here is the grappling script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class graplin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject cam;
    public float hookSpeed;
    Vector3 graPos;
    bool canClick = true;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,(transform.position - cam.transform.position).normalized,out hit))
            {
                graPos = hit.point;
                canClick = true;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) & canClick)
        {
            player.GetComponent<playerControler>().enabled = false;
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;

            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = ((graPos - player.transform.position).normalized * hookSpeed);

        }
        if(!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            canClick = false;
            player.GetComponent<playerControler>().enabled = true;
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
```

}

here is the video I took of the problem
[the video](https://youtu.be/DuICt4PKHv4)

Comment: 1) Do you have interpolation enabled on your player's rigidbody? 2) Does anything in your other player or camera control scripts modify an object's transform position or rotation? 3) Why do your walls have rigidbodies? 4) Can you show us an example of the jitter you're observing?

Comment: I tough adding a rigidbody would help. Also interpolation is set to none, what does it do ? No I was careful about modifying the player position. I'm trying going to add a recording of my problem

Comment: Interpolation smooths out jitter (technically "judder" in this case) for fast moving objects. It adjusts for the time difference between the physics update step and the frame render.

Comment: Oh ok, I had no idea. I added the link of the video